# How can I run a neovim script from command line and exit on the first error?

Tags: neovim

I'm attempting to create a Dockerfile that installs nvim along with some treesitter dependencies. I have a script that installs vim-plug and then calls `nvim --headless +PlugInstall +qa` followed by `nvim --headless +"TSInstall $name" +qa`.

When building the image it's difficult to tell if something fails when running the vim commands because it always has an exit code of `0`. Is there a way to run a vim and/or lua script and have it exit on the first error, while causing vim to exit with exit code 1?

Comment: did it give any error messages which you can parse?

Comment: Check v:error and use `cquit`. You might want to write a vimscript file and execute with -S or similar.